# What's the difference between the following php packages?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, apache2, php

The following message prompts when you just simply do: `sudo apt-get install php`, which basically installs all of the related php packages, I believe:

```
libapache2-mod-php7.2 php-common php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline
```

Do I need to install all of these? My server Ubuntu prompted me to perform `sudo apt install php7.2-cli`. Most Sources online don't specify what the difference between the packages is?

Answer (score 1):

You can issue `apt-cache show PKG` (or just `apt show PKG`) command to get package description, in this case we'll start by issuing the command to each package you want to know about.

- `libapache2-mod-php7.2`

  > This package provides the PHP module for the Apache 2 webserver (as found in the apache2-mpm-prefork package).  Please note that this package ONLY works with Apache's prefork MPM, as it is not compiled thread-safe.
- `php-common`

  > This package contains common utilities shared among all packaged PHP versions.
- `php7.2-common`

  > This package provides the documentation, examples and common module(s) for PHP.
- `php7.2-cli`

  > This package provides the `/usr/bin/php7.2` command interpreter, useful for testing PHP scripts from a shell or performing general shell scripting tasks.
- `php7.2-json`

  > This package provides the JSON module(s) for PHP.
- `php7.2-opcache`

  > This package provides the Zend OpCache module(s) for PHP.
- `php7.2-readline`

  > This package provides the readline module(s) for PHP.

If you plan to use apache as your webserver, then leave out as it be because by default `apt` will install apache integration with php— otherwise just installing `php7.2-cli` will get rid of apache dependencies for good.